# How do I replace text in selected range with blanks of same length?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The code below ends up deleting the text- I want to keep the length of the found content and replace the actual shaded area with blanks or some random char like *, retaining the shading.

Tried to do things with char counts and using String(charcount, " ")
to no avail.

```
   Sub changecolor()
   Dim rg As Range
   Set rg = ActiveDocument.Range
   With rg.Find
   .Format = True
   .Text = ""
   .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   While .Execute
   rg.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
   rg.Font.Color = wdColorBlack
   rg.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
   Wend
   End With
   Call ReplaceBlack
   End Sub


  Sub ReplaceBlack()
'
    With Selection.Find
     charc = Len(Selection)
    .Format = True
    .Text = ""
    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Replacement.Text = String(charc, "")

    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

   End Sub
```

Comment: Did the answer below solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in the question is that it's measuring the length of `Selection` before `Find` has been executed. Thus, the number of characters will always be whatever was selected at that point.

The Find must first be executed, and for each instance of the Shading since the length of the content that's shaded could vary. Since this needs to be done for each instance, it can be incorporated into the original loop, rather than be performed in a second loop.

The code below moves the entire color change, font change *and* text replacement to `ReplaceBlack`, using the target `Range` object `rg`, which is passed to `ReplaceBlack` as a parameter.

```
Sub changecolor()
   Dim rg As Range
   Set rg = ActiveDocument.Range
   With rg.Find
    .Format = True
    .Text = ""
    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    While .Execute
        ReplaceBlack rg
    Wend
   End With

End Sub

Sub ReplaceBlack(rg As Range)
      rg.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      rg.Font.color = wdColorBlack
      charc = Len(rg)
      rg.Text = String(charc, "*")
      rg.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
 End Sub
```